# Converting a json file with escaped unicode to real unicode while retaining escaped double quotes

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding

I have an escaped unicode string in a json file, for example this:

```
{"word": "\u043a\u043e\u0433\u0434\u0430 \u0440\u0430\u043a \u043d\u0430 \u0433\u043e\u0440\u0435 \u0441\u0432\u0438\u0441\u0442\u043d\u0435\u0442",
"glosses": ["when pigs fly, never (lit., \"when the crawfish whistles on the mountain\")"]}}
```

I want to convert this file so that proper unicode is shown. In Python I found several suggestions for this, for example this:

```
import codecs

# opens a file and converts input to true Unicode
with codecs.open("kaikki.org-dictionary-Russian.json", "rb", "unicode_escape") as my_input:
contents = my_input.read()
# type(contents) = unicode 

# opens a file with UTF-8 encoding
with codecs.open("utf8-dictionary.json", "wb", "utf8") as my_output:
my_output.write(contents)
```

I also wrote another similar function without using "codecs", but both got the same result. After executing the command, I get:

```
{"word": "когда рак на горе свистнет", 
"glosses": ["when pigs fly, never (lit., "when the crawfish whistles on the mountain")"]}
```

The escaped double quotes are not escaped anymore, which makes the JSON invalid. How can I prevent this?

Edit:  I forgot to mention that I have the file in a jsonlines format, so each line is a json object beginning and ending with { ... }.

Thanks for all the help! My final solution:

```
import json

with open("kaikki.org-dictionary-Russian.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as input, \
open("utf8-dictionary-4.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as out:
for line in input:
    data = json.loads(line) 
    json.dump(data, out, ensure_ascii=False)
    out.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `json` library for working with JSON data.
It will make sure that serialised data are valid JSON, and it has a few options for controlling the output, such as as indented pretty-printing and non-ASCII characters without escaping.

First, parse the data with `json.load()`:

```
>>> with open("kaikki.org-dictionary-Russian.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
```

Note: in Python 3, there's no need to use the `codecs` library for reading/writing files. Just specify the file encoding in the built-in `open` function.

The serialise the data again, now using the `ensure_ascii` option, which leads to minimal use of escape sequences (only double quotes, newlines and tabs are escaped IIRC):

```
>>> with open("utf8-dictionary.json", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
...     json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I forgot to mention that I have the file in a jsonlines format, so each line is a json object beginning and ending with { ... }. This means that I can't load it directly into the json.load function unfortunately.

Comment: @Pux ok, well, then *iterate over the file line-by-line* and use `json.loads`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh thank you, I forgot this function existed.